# How to zoom to the extent of a Qgsvectolayer using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers

Anyone know how to zoom to the extent of a Vectorlayer in QGIS using python plugin?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'd get the app's Map Canvas and set its extent.

```
canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
```

[You might want to read this tutorial](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/index.html).

Comment: to use a custom extent use: canvas.setExtent(QgsRectangle(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax))

Comment: Additionally, you may use canvas.refresh()

Answer (score 1):

This won't work if the CRS of the vector layer is different from the CRS of the project. This could be a better solution: project the extent of the vector layer to the CRS of the project before zooming, like so:

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(the_layer.crs(),
                               canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs())
canvas.setExtent(xform.transform(the_layer.extent()))
canvas.refresh()
```

Comment: the `mapRenderer()` is deprecated though. See: https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsMapCanvas.html